# How to determine if a point is within a rectangle using only two plotted corners

Tags: python

I am currently working on assignment problem about determining if a giving point is within a rectangle that I only have the two plotted corner of. Here is the question.

Write a function isIn() which returns boolean True if a point is within a rectangle specified by two sets of coordinates and boolean False if the point is outside the rectangle. The function should accept three parameters:

- the first parameter is a set of coordinates which defines one of the corners of the rectangle,
- the second parameter is also a set of coordinates that defines the second corner,
- the third set of coordinates defines a single point which is being tested.
- For example,

`isIn((1,2), (3,4), (1.5, 3.2)) should return True, isIn((4,3.5), (2,1), (3, 2)) should return True, isIn((-1,0), (5,5), (6,0)) should return False, isIn((4,1), (2,4), (2.5,4.5)) should return False.`
Test your function with at least 2 different sets of data points in addition to the examples above.

NOTES:

- If the point being tested is on the side of the rectangle, consider it to be within the rectangle. For example, if the rectangle is defined as (1,2), (3,4) and the point is (2,2), the function should return True.
- In this assignment, we assume that the edges of the rectangle are parallel to coordinate axes.
  We also assume that the first parameter does not always represent the left corner of the rectangle and the second parameter is not always the right corner. The function should work correctly either way. Please note the second test condition above where the first parameter, (4,3.5), represents the top-right corner and the second parameter, (2,1), represents left-bottom corner.

This is what I have so far. Keep in mind i havent touched my highschool math skills in 8 plus years.

Input:

```
`import numpy as np
def isIn(firstCorner=(0,0), secondCorner=(0,0), point=(0,0)):
    # YOUR CODE HERE

    points_dic={"firstCorner":firstCorner,"secondCorner":secondCorner}
    points =list((points_dic.values()))
    
    if points[0] >= points[1]:
        points=[points[1],points[0]]
        print('switch')

    firstCorner = points[0]
    secondCorner = points[1]
 
    x1=(firstCorner[0])
    y1=(firstCorner[1])

    x3=(secondCorner[0])
    y3=(secondCorner[1])

    x2=x1
    y2=y3

    x4=x3
    y4=y1

    px=(point[0])
    py=(point[1])

    ta1 = .5*(x1*(y2-py)+x2*(py-y1)+px*(y1-y2))
    ta2 = .5*(x2*(y3-py)+x3*(py-y2)+px*(y2-y3))
    ta3 = .5*(x3*(y4-py)+x4*(py-y3)+px*(y3-y4))
    ta4 = .5*(x4*(y1-py)+x1*(py-y4)+px*(y4-y1))
    ra = (x1-x3)*(y1-y3)
    rac = (ta1+ta2+ta3+ta4)
    print("Rectangle Area is =",ra,"\nTraiangles added =",rac)
    print(ta1,ta2,ta3,ta4)
def main():
    print(isIn((1,2), (3,4), (1.5, 3.2)))
main()`
```

My goal is to see if the area of 4 triangles, created using 2 corners of the rectangle and the given point as the thrid plot, have the same area as the rectangle. If the areas match then the point is inside, if they dont then its not.

So far ive managed this outcome.

Output:

`'Rectangle Area is = 4  Traiangles added = -4.0 -0.5 -0.7999999999999998 -1.5 -1.2000000000000002  None'`

I'm not sure why the area of the 4 triangles is coming out as negative. I assume it's my math which is my weakest knowledge point. This is a course assignment so any pointers without outright answering the question would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The question title is "How to determine if a point is within a rectangle using only two plotted corners", but in the post you also say "My goal is to see if the area of 4 triangles, created using 2 corners of the rectangle and the given point as the thrid plot, have the same area as the rectangle".  So.... what is your actual question??

Comment: If the test point x lies on or between the corner x coordinates and the test point y lies on or between the corner y coordinates … And if the corner points aren’t opposing corners then the problem would be impossible anyway. Forget areas: you aren’t looking at a general polygon.

Comment: Two points only specify a line, and are not sufficient to define a rectangle. The question, as stated, cannot be solved. Three points are needed to uniquely define a rectangle, or two points that are guaranteed to be diagonally opposite.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, it is two sets of points representing opposite corners from what I understand.

Comment: @lastchance The corners are assumed to be opposite. I tried comparing to see if the given point was between X1/X2 and Y1/Y2 , but ran into trouble when it came to negative numbers

Comment: @JohnGordon Maybe I should have used the word "approach" instead of "goal". Apologies if i confused you

Comment: Just check min(x1,x2)<=x<=max(x1,x2) and min(y1,y2)<=y<=max(y1,y2)

Comment: @lastchance I don't think that will work if the rectangle is rotated, i.e. not parallel to the x,y axes.

Comment: @Mark Setchell - the original question says ```In this assignment, we assume that the edges of the rectangle are parallel to coordinate axes.```

Comment: @lastchance Cool, well spotted. I didn't see that